# Máximo número de votos diarios. ¿Cómo llego a la medalla Vóx Populi?

Tags: soporte, medallas

¿Cuál es el número máximo de votos por día?
¿El límite sube conforme sube la reputación?

Perdón la pregunta estúpida, pero he intentado tres veces obtener la medalla de 40 votos positivos en un sólo día ([Vóx populi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/71/vox-populi)), y siempre me quedan faltando algunos para completarla.

Comment: espero que en tus intentos de obtener la medalla hallas votado con responsabilidad.

Comment: Claro que son responsables amigo, imposible que en las tantas preguntas que hay no hallan preguntas y respuestas buenas, aunque me preocupa que se acaben las preguntas valiosas.

Comment: @SalahAdDin quizás te interese [¿Cómo etiquetamos las preguntas de Django?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3210/127)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El límite de votos [se calcula de forma un tanto compleja](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/136880) y depende de *a qué* votas. En resúmen, si quieres poder votar 40 veces en un día, <s>debes</s> *la forma más fácil es* votar sólo preguntas (no respuestas).

Comment: Según entiendo lo que dice en ese link si votas 24 respuestas y 16 preguntas funcionaria también.

Comment: Cierto. ¡Editado, gracias!

Comment: Gracias hombre. Aunque así es más difícil. jajajajajajajja

Comment: Esto me ha servido. Gracias @Konamiman